# Laravel problem with @foreach loop in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

From Ziparchive want `name` and `size` of files in Zip file. Problem for me is how can add `name` and `size` to table in blade view.

`controller`:

```
    $ziparchive = new \ZipArchive(); 
    $ziparchive->open($fileName);
    $filenames = [];
    $filesizes = [];
    if(!empty($ziparchive)){         
        for( $i = 0; $i < $ziparchive->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
            $stat = $ziparchive->statIndex( $i ); 
            $filenames[]= basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL;
            $filesizes[]= basename( $stat['size'] );

    return view('view',["filenames"=>$filenames,"filesizes"=>$filesizes]);
```

`dd($filenames, $filesizes)` return two arrays:

```
 1.png
 2.png
 3.png
 4.png

 10
 12
 13
 796
```

in `view.blade.php`

```
@foreach($filenames as $filename )
    @foreach($filesizes as $filesize)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$filename}}</td>
            <td>{{$filesize}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

return in table this:

```
 1.png 10
 1.png 12
 1.png 13
 1.png 796
 2.png 10
 2.png 12
 2.png 13
 ....
```

what do i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```php
@foreach($filenames as $key => $filename )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $filename }}</td>
        <td>{{ $filesizes[$key] ?? "" }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

as both `$filenames` and `$filesizes` same index have same value so you can use index to get value from `$filesizes[index]`